# Python savetxt write as int

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, numpy

I am trying to write an array out to a text file and I want each element to be written as an `int` type.

I am using

```
np.savetxt(outfile_name, array, comments = '')
```

to write out the file. I converted `array` from `float` to `int` using

```
array = array.astype(int)
```

When I printed `array` in the program, the array came out as `int`, but when I wrote it to a text file, the file looks like:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00
1.000000000000000000e+00 1.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00 0.000000000000000000e+00
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried specifying a format, per [the documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)?

```
np.savetxt(outfile_name, array, fmt="%d", comments='')
                              # ^ format as signed decimal integer
```

This uses the standard [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

Comment: I notice that when the array includes '0.3' the output ends up as '1' instead of '0'. Do you know how to change it so that the result rounds down for 0-0.4 and up for 0.5-0.9?

Comment: probably the easiest way is to subtract `0.5` from the array.

Comment: Use [`np.round`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.round_.html) rather than `astype`